# Query rails with condition and order with a limit of records returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to perform a query on rails where I return 10 products from a specific category with the highest Status.

I've come up with the query below which isn't returning anything. I've tried many variations of it but can't seem to get this working. Seems very basic so I'm quite frustrated. Can anyone assist?

```
Product.where("category_id = 4").limit(10).order("status desc") do |a|

    puts a.name

end
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can pass a block to the query method, are you certain of that? what do you expect `a` to be?

Comment: name is the product name, so it should render each name of the product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Product.where("category_id = 4").order("status desc").limit(10).each do |a|
    puts a.name
end
```

or this

```
p Product.where("category_id = 4").order("status desc").limit(10).collect(&:name)
```

Comment: Hmm @Vimsha I have noted a problem with this, it doesn't seem to be returning the items with the largest status, but rather returning 10 items and sorting them by Status. Any ideas?

Comment: Do the order first and then limit. See my updated answer

Comment: Hey mate unfortunately it looks like it's still not returning the items with the highest status.. weird. Any ideas?

Comment: Oops this works, just had a default scope that was effecting it, thanks mate!